# Can't send a message to queue on WIldfly 11

Tags: java, jms, wildfly

I am having this small message producer:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Properties env = new Properties();
        InputStream is = Producer.class.getResourceAsStream("/jms.properties");
        env.load(is);
        Context context = new InitialContext(env);
        ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
        Destination queue = (Destination) context.lookup("jms/demoQueue");

        JMSContext jmsContext = factory.createContext();
        jmsContext.createProducer().send(queue, "Message");

    }
```

Using the following properties:

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = http-remoting://localhost:8080
java.naming.security.principal = alex
java.naming.security.credentials = password
messagingProvider = demo
connectionFactoryNames = QueueFactory
queue.queueReq = jms.queueReq
queue.queueResp = jms.queueResp
```

But I get an exception:

> "Caused by: javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ119031: Unable to
>   validate user"

I believe I have misconfigured something on the server. But what exactly? Security settings have pattern: # with role guest and admin. I don't see anything else related to security

Answer (score 2):

Call the overloaded `createContext()` method with 2 arguments:

`JMSContext context = factory.createContext("alex", "password");`

Then it should work if the "alex" user has correct role assigned.

I remember I had a discussion with developers about how the `createContext()` should work (it was in relation with Elytron - the new securtity subsystem), and the decission for now was like: *It works as designed, but it can be enhanced in the future.*

See [comments in JBEAP-10527](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-10527) for details.